# DB2 select query to find tablenames ends with '_H'

Tags: sql, select, db2

I have a requirement to select all the table names ends with '_H'.
I tried below query but it is giving me all the table names ends with 'H'.

Please help me to query tablenames ends with '_H'.

```
db2 "SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO where  tabname like '%_H' with ur"
```

YFS_PRICE_MATCH    -> this is not expected in query results.

YFS_PROMOTION_AWARD_H  -> This is expected result.

Comment: `_` is a Wildcard equivalent for `?` in DB2. try to escape it with `\_`

Comment: Hi Jens, 

Thanks for the reply.

I tried all the below patterns but result set is empty.
'%\_H'
'\_H'
'\\_H'
'%\\_H'

Comment: read here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_likepredicate.html maybe this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ANSI SQL, you can use `escape` clause to search for wildcard as below to get your desired result.

```
 SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO where tabname like '%x_h' escape 'x';
```

in `DB2/z`, another option can be to use the propriety short form as below.

```
 SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO where tabname like {escape 'x'} '%x_h';
```

In both of the above queries `x` is used as `escape` character. you can choose any based on your data.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Below one worked for me.

SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO where tabname like '%x_h' escape 'x';

Platform: DB2 10.5 in AIX

Answer (score 0):

In Db2 and some other SQL database systems the characters `?` and `_` denote a wildcard in the `LIKE` expression. To use the `_` or `?` as a regular character you need to escape them. In Db2 the escape character is the [plus sign (`+`) on Db2 for z/OS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_likepredicate.html) or the [backslash (`\`) on Db2 (Linux, UNIX, Windows)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000751.html). So, depending on the platform, your expression would look like
`%+_H` or `%\_H`.